# data.frame columns as tabular row labels in R

Tags: r, paste, sweave, tabular

I am trying to make a table in R/Sweave using the tabular command.  I want the row labels to be the headings of my data frame `consca`. (Each column is a question, and each row is a student's responses to each question.) The command I am using is this:

```
latex(tabular(Heading('Questions')*(paste(labels(consca)[[2]],collapse='+')) ~ (n=1) + (mn + 
          sdev),data=consca))
```

Which throws this error:

```
Error in term2table(rows[[i]], cols[[j]], data, n) : 
Argument paste(labels(consca)[[2]], collapse = "+") is not length 298
```

The paste argument works...

```
 paste(labels(consca)[[2]],collapse='+')
    [1] "Q02+Q03+Q06+Q17+Q19+Q25+Q31+Q33+Q36+Q39+Q45+Q50"
```

And produces the output I desire:

```
latex(tabular(Heading('Questions')*(Q02+Q03+Q06+Q17+Q19+Q25+Q31+Q33+Q36+Q39+Q45+Q50) ~ (n=1) + 
                (mn + sdev),data=consca))
```

However, I want to do this with multiple scales (i.e. I want to change `consca` to other objects and I want to eliminate the copy/paste step.)

I have fiddled with `eval` and `as.symbol`, but to no avail.  Perhaps I am not using them in the right way.

OK, and for those of you who will want a minimal reproducible example, here goes:

```
require(tables)
a <- rnorm(10)
b <- rnorm(10,2)
c <- rnorm(10,100)
x <- data.frame(a,b,c)
# This works:
tabular(a+b+c ~ (mean + sd), x)
# This fails:
tabular(paste(labels(x)[[2]],collapse='+') ~ (mean+sd),x)
# Even though:
paste(labels(x)[[2]],collapse='+')
[1] "a+b+c"
```

Comment: You should mention the package(s) you're using...I'm assuming **Hmisc**?

Comment: That would be the [tables package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf). The misbehavior is all in the tabular function. I have edited my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround using the `describe` function in the `psych` package.  (Ultimately, I wanted more than the mean and sd, and the describe function automatically calculates them.) This creates a data.frame, which is trivial to turn into a \LaTeX table.